# Two bytes snowman return 76 bytes per sys.getsizeof()

Tags: python

I checked the unicode of snowman

```
In [37]: snowman = "\u2603"
In [38]: snowman
Out[38]: '☃'
```

As the above, '☃' takes 2 bytes

However, when I tried to get its size:

```
In [39]: sys.getsizeof(snowman)
Out[39]: 76
```

It indicates that snowman takes 76 bytes

Help on built-in function getsizeof in module sys:

```
getsizeof(...)
    getsizeof(object, default) -> int

    Return the size of object in bytes.
```

How could I understand it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Python being a dynamically typed language, all objects carry type information with them. In C, an int just needs the bytes to represent the int; the knowledge that it is an int is implicit in the code. Not so in Python, not with numbers, and especially not with strings, which have become more complicated since [PEP 393](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0393/) was adopted. As you can see, both in the PEP and in the CPython source [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Include/unicodeobject.h), Python can represent strings in one of several representations. Unfortunately, the header information is rather large; a string not only has the header that every Python object has, it also has a flag structure, it carries its hash, its byte length, its true length, and more, in an onion-like structure that has more layers the more complex the representation. Thus, ASCII-only strings are quite short in comparison (`PyASCIIObject`); but a string that contains a character that is outside the ASCII range gets a new layer (`PyCompactUnicodeObject`). `sys.getsizeof` doesn't just give you the string length; it gives you the entirety of memory allocated for the object, including the header information, and it adds up.